# Columnas no deben contener valores nulos

Tags: flutter, dart

obtengo este error:

> The following assertion was thrown building LoginPage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state:
> _LoginPageState#b7ebe):
> Stack's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 1
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> LoginPage

Por lo que veo el error me dice que hay valores nulos en children, como evito eso?

```
Widget _loginForm(BuildContext context) {
// final bloc = Provider.of(context);
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SafeArea(
              child: Container(
            height: 180.0,
          )),
          Container(
            width: size.width * 0.85,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      blurRadius: 1.0,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                      spreadRadius: 1.0)
                ]),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "LOGIN",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                ),
                _crearEmail(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                ),
                _crearPassword(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                ),
                _crearBoton(context)
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
   },
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu funcion no esta retornando nada. Estas construyendo un BlocBuilder pero no lo estas usando.

```
return BlocBuilder....
```

Comment: Gracias, se me pasó por alto ese detalle